# Android Cannot disable listview header dividers

Tags: android, listview, divider

I am trying to disable dividers on a listview header.

**setHeaderDividersEnabled(false)** : KO

**android:headerDividersEnabled="false"** : KO

The only think that seems to work is to set dividers height to 0 which removes all dividers. :/

I think that an issue with Android 4.4.2 and above. Can someone helps me please :).

Br.

[Edit]: I cannot change the divider for the rest of the listview I need to disable it only for the header:s

Answer (score 1):

One option would be changing the color of your divider for a transparent color:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for your response but because of some design constraints i cannot change the color of the divider, I am really in the need to disable the divider only for the header.